# using two-dimensional array for store several strings

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, substring

I wrote a function in C that search if a substring is in a string and it's OK, but when I use it in a array of strings I face an error. Please see this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int substring(char*, char*);

main()
{
    char student[100][7];
    int counter = 0;
    int finish =1;
    char s1[4];
    while(finish){
        printf("please Enter Student Number: \n");
        scanf("%s", student[counter]);
        counter++;
        printf("Do you want to exit? 1/0");
        scanf("%d", &finish);
    }
    printf("Now, You can search in Student numbers\n");
    printf("Enter a number to search: ");
    scanf("%s", s1);
    for(int i  = 0; i < counter; i++){
        printf("%d : %s\n", i, student[i]);
        if(substring(student[i],s1) == 1)
            printf("%s", student[i]);
    }

    getch();
}

int substring(char *s1,char *s2)
{
    int f=0;
    for(; *s1 !='\0';)
    {
        if(*s2=='\0')
            break;
        for(;*s2 !='\0';)
        {
            if(*s1==*s2)
            {
                f=1;
                s1 ++;
                s2 ++;
            }
            else
            {
                f=0;
                s1++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(f==0)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: If you format the code, it'll be much easier to debug

Comment: What is the error you face?

Comment: You do a scanf("%s", s1); and then right after that gets(s1).

Comment: That code is a mess. What is the `getch()` behind the returns supposed to be? Why are you using an `int` to store booleans (as opposed to a `bool`)? Why are you using the deprecated and insecure `gets()` method?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can test for substring using simple state machine:

```
int substring(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    enum
    {
        search, start_match
    } state = search;
    const char *m;

    while(*s1 != '\0')
    {
        switch(state)
        {
        case search:
            if(*s2 == '\0')
                return 0;
            else if(*s2 == *s1)
            {
                state = start_match;
                m = s2 + 1;
            }
            break;
        case start_match:
            if(*m == '\0')
                return 1;
            else if(*m != *s1)
                state = search;
            else
                ++m;
        }

        ++s1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also you may use the standard [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) function.